# Link to "email subscription management"

Tags: feature-request, email-notification, subscription

Subscription/email notification management is a feature that is not present on profile management screens (or rather it's three levels deep in them - that is click-click-click). A user who hasn't memorized the path must look hard to find it.

I think it is a major functional area and deserves a more prominent spot on the preferences screens.

- Why not having indicators and *edit* links straight on *preferences*|*Favorite Tags*, showing subscribed or not (color-code the tag maybe) + frequency + "edit" link/icon.
  something like this:
  [image]

Without it the management of this feature is hidden and hard to find.

- Also - not 100% sure, but I thought I saw an alternative (to the "filters") subscription mechanism - one through favorite tags. Am I right, and if yes could someone explain if they're really different and how to get to the "favorites" subscriptions?

**ADDITION**
The "parallel" subscription management is on StackExchange. There, I definitely see different settings than the "favorite tags" on SO - same tags, same site - just two different subscriptions. That's confusing, to say the least.

Suggestion: Since "subscriptions" on StackExchange and "favorite tags" on StackOverflow overlap, I think they need to be consolidated. At least to the point individual subscriptions intersect (in case there are other reasons to keep them segregated).
**END ADDITION**

Comment: When writing up a feature request, it is customary to describe the problem you're trying to solve, or what potential benefit it would provide.  I'm not sure you've done that adequately here.

Comment: I made an edit, but don't you think that it's very clear what deficiency prompted this? I have been trying for two days, in the 1-2 min. I have available, to change email preferences, and subscription management is simply nowhere to be found.

Comment: That's much better.